# How prevent Jenkins job from dropping environment variables after build step

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins

I have Jenkins job with several steps after build step performed.

Before starting job `EnvInject` creates several dozen of environment variables. Say I need `$FOO` and `$BAR` variables from those created by `EnvInject` to be available for post build step.

How can I get this variables?

Comment: "several steps after build step", "available for post build step" – Are these additional _Build steps_ or _Post build actions?_ Of which type?

Comment: @GeroldBroser, post build action

Comment: Which type(s) of post-build actions?